# Display input from text-fields on webpage XSS vulnerability or not? (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xss

Currently I am developing an eCommerce platform with Node and React where the user has to fill in a form  their shipment information + email and after they submit that information they receive the shipping cost calculation. The thing is I also want to display the submitted information on the webpage in case the user misspelled something and needs to edit the information. I will not use dangerouslySetInnerHtml for this I was more thinking of just rendering the state values of the input. Can I do that or am I enabling an XSS attack by displaying the users input on to the webpage?

From what I understand the values of the state variable will not be rendered as HTML and instead as a string. Therefore, I should be fine doing this?

Comment: Can you add some more code to get context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Provided that you are not using dangerouslySetInnerHtml, the content that was input by your users will render as text.

Answer (score 0):

By using use dangerouslySetInnerHtm you will be putting yourself at risk of an XSS attack by displaying the user's input on the webpage, the best way as is to do the following:-

1. Render the data submitted by the user (shipment information) on a
   page and put an edit button
2. When the edit button is clicked, the
   data of the object that you want to edit will be accessed by ID
3. Render the data to a component that contains editable field and a
   submit button which will be clicked once editing the data is done